# ChartJS - this.setValue is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

working on a Chart.JS line chart. Renders fine, tooltips are fine, but when I hover over a line (not the chart as a whole, just a line) I get

```
Chart.js:1647 Uncaught TypeError: this.setValues is not a function
    at new Color (Chart.js:1647)
    at Color (Chart.js:1629)
    at Object.helpers$1.color (Chart.js:10902)
    at helpers$1.getHoverColor (Chart.js:10909)
    at ChartElement.setHoverStyle (Chart.js:6137)
    at Chart.updateHoverStyle (Chart.js:10143)
    at Chart.handleEvent (Chart.js:10241)
    at Chart.eventHandler (Chart.js:10167)
    at listener (Chart.js:10100)
    at HTMLCanvasElement.proxies.<computed> (Chart.js:7830)
```

This is using the lib inside a React functional component with `import {Chart} from 'chart.js'` and rendering in a hook, so:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        lineChart = new Chart(canvasRef.current, {
            type: 'line',
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: props.unitCode,
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: false,
                },
                hover: {
                    mode: 'nearest',
                    intersect: true
                },     
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [
                        {
                           scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Time'
                            },
                            type: 'time',
                            distribution: 'linear',
                            
                        }
                    ],
                    yAxes: [
                        {
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Mw'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            data: {
                datasets: [ 
                    {
                        label: 'PN Mw',
                        data: series[MetricType.Pn],
                        borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
                        fill: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
                        pointRadius: 0,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        lineTension: 1,
                        showLine: true,
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'MEL Mw',
                        data: series[MetricType.Mel],
                        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
                        fill: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
                        pointRadius: 0,
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        lineTension: 1,
                        showLine: true
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Mil Mw',
                        data: series[MetricType.Mil],
                        borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 255)',
                        fill: 'rgb(0, 0, 255)',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 255)',
                        pointRadius: 0,
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        lineTension: 1,
                        showLine: true
                    }
                ]
            }
        });
    })
```

The latest version of ChartJS, React, Chrome.  Also happens in Firefox, so not browser-specific.

Ideas welcome :-)
Thanks

Comment: have you install [react-chartjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs) ?  I think that your import is not correct. I would suggest you to use [react-chartjs-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2)

Comment: I'll give it a try and report back.